# Hypothesis testing statstics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

The management of a fast-food restaurant claims only 50% of its customers read the
nutritional labels attached to the containers of its products. A random sample of
92 people were surveyed and asked if they had read the nutritional labels. Of those
surveyed, 55 had read the labels. Do these data indicate that the true percentage
is not as claimed by management? Use a 4% signicance level.

I was just wondering if this is a t-distribution or a standard normal distribution? And If we need to use proportions?

Comment: Please read the [self-study tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question as discussed there -- which is to say, you would show an attempt at the question and describe the specific problems encountered (if you actually try doing a t-test you should strike one such problem immediately). Does it seem like 50% and 55 out of 92 would be considered to be proportions?

Comment: gung's question on your other answer "*How does one decide whether to use the normal or the t distribution? What are the criteria for selecting between them?*" is exactly the issue that you need to address here. Were you really given no criteria whatever for working out when to do one test or another?

Answer (score 0):

Here, Binomial assumption is good, as each customer either read or not read independently.

You can use "standard normal distribution" by applying Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: This may go somewhat beyond the 'hints and guidance' the `self-study` [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) asks us to stick to.

Comment: ok but how can you know if its a proportion?

Comment: "The management of a fast-food restaurant claims only 50% of its customers read the nutritional labels"

Comment: Just one last question. This is a two-tailed test right? because alternative hypothesis is p is not equal to 50%

Comment: Yes! You'd test if upper or lower 2% to reject $H_0$

Answer (score 0):

In this case,

$H_0 = 0.5$

$H_a \neq 0.5$

Under the null hypothesis, your test statistics will be (after applying CLT):

$z = \frac{p-p_0}{\sqrt{\frac{p_0(1-p_0)}{n}}}$

with $\alpha = 0.04$ and

Using z table, we find $Pr(Z \geq{1.877})$

Then the p value will be 2*$Pr(Z \geq{1.877})$

Comment: Why is it bigger or equal? I mean the Z value?

Comment: Oh, we have to find the probability in the upper tail

Comment: how come? Isn't it a two-tailed probability?

Comment: Yeah, that's why we need to add the lower tail part as well..

Comment: Ok but we need to divide alpha by 2, no?